# I have Full Cookie banner but close button dont work at all

Tags: cookies, popup

It's full cookie popup in HTML CSS JS i have but close button don't react

```
    <div id="cookban" class="hide">
        <a href="#" id="close" class="close" >CLOSE</a>
        <a href="privacy.html" target="_blank">PRIVACY</a>
        <a href="#" id="accept" class="accept" >ACCEPT</a>
    </div>
```

in CSS there's some style and popup is off when cookie exist.

```
    #cookban.hide{
     opacity: 0;
    }
```

in JS i use setItem and getItem here's full JS code

```
       const cookieStorage = {
       getItem: (key) => {
       
       const cookies = document.cookie
         .split(';')
         .map(cookie => cookie.split('='))
         .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({ ...acc, [key.trim()]: value}), {});
       
         return cookies[key];
       
       },
         setItem: (key, value) => {
           document.cookie = `${key}=${value}`;
       
         },
       };
   
      
   
   const storageType = cookieStorage;
   const consentPropertyName = 'owner';
   
   const shouldShowPopup = () => !storageType.getItem(consentPropertyName);
   const saveToStorage = () => storageType.setItem(consentPropertyName, true);
   
   window.onload = () => {

const consentPopup = document.getElementById('cookban');
const acceptBtn = document.getElementById('accept');
const closeBtn = document.getElementById('close');



const acceptFn = event =>{
   saveToStorage(storageType);
   consentPopup.classList.add('hide');
};

const closeFn = event =>{
  consentPopup.classList.add('hide');
};


acceptBtn.addEventListener('click', acceptFn);
   if (shouldShowPopup(storageType)) {
       setTimeout(() => {
       consentPopup.classList.remove('hide');
   }, 200);
   };
   };

closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeFn);
   if (shouldShowPopup(storageType)) {
       setTimeout(() => {
       consentPopup.classList.remove('hide');
    }, 200);
    };
```

Close button dont hide my popup it do nothing, how to kill this popup and dont create a cookie ?

Answer (score 0):

OK I GOT THIS ... i did second function to close button in another JQ file to kill this banner